# How to setup Hive on a multiple node?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hive

i already sat up hive over hbase and hadoop for a single master and a single node and it works perfectly with mapreduce job ,but when i sat up hive for a single master and multiple nodes there is a problem

could anyone help me how to set up for multiple hbase nodes ?

Comment: Do you face any error or any problem while doing the setup? following link will provide more details on how it is to be done. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/cluster_setup.html

Answer (score 0):

try following steps mentioned in :
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/cluster_setup.html